# ValueError: Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to work on a problem where I will have a data frame,say df, with Name & age & I need to generate another dataframe with name & gender in for loop & I need to merge the data frame generated in for loop with df to get gender in df. So I tried below code before solving my problem

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Age': [45, 38], 'Name': ['John', 'Emily']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d1={'Gender':['M'],'Name':['John']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

df3 = df.merge(df1, on=['Name'], how='left', indicator=True)
df3

d2={'Gender':['F'],'Name':['Emily']}
df4=pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df5=df3.merge(df4, on=['Name'], how='left', indicator=True)
```

I'm getting following error while I'm running the last line.

```
 "Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column")

ValueError: Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column
```

Can you please suggest me how to solve this problem in python 3.x?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do (as another person answered). But to understand WHY you are getting the error, please read below.

Because you did one merge,  you now have a column called `_merge` in the your df3. And when you merge again, you cannot create yet another `_merge`.

As an aside and for future reference, right now you have `indicator=True` but alternatively you can pass in a string such as `indicator='exists'` Then your new column that "indicates" how you joined will be called `exists` and you can select it by doing `df5['exists']`

Check out this simple example and walking through it in a `repl`

```
>>> df1
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    b    c
2    d    e
>>> df2
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    b    c
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='col1', how='left', indicator=True)
  col1 col2_x col2_y     _merge
0    a      b      b       both
1    b      c      c       both
2    d      e    NaN  left_only
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='col1', how='left', indicator=True)
>>> df4 = pd.DataFrame([['d', 'e']], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
>>> df3.merge(df4, on='col1', how='left', indicator=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/devtools/uat/anaconda4321/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4722, in merge
copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "/usr/local/devtools/uat/anaconda4321/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 54, in merge
return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/devtools/uat/anaconda4321/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 567, in get_result
self.left, self.right)
  File "/usr/local/devtools/uat/anaconda4321/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 605, in _indicator_pre_merge
"Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column")
ValueError: Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column
>>> df3.merge(df4, on='col1', how='left', indicator='exists')
  col1 col2_x col2_y     _merge col2     exists
0    a      b      b       both  NaN  left_only
1    b      c      c       both  NaN  left_only
2    d      e    NaN  left_only    e       both
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do a different way than others may think. I will use [`map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
# merging both gender dataframes together for convenience 
gender = pd.concat([df1,df4])

# creating a column the same as 'Name' but calling it gender
df['Gender'] = df['Name']

# creating a dictionary with the name as the key, and gender as value
gender_dict = gender.set_index('Name')['Gender'].to_dict()
# output as {'Emily': 'F', 'John': 'M'}

# remapping the name in place of the gender
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].map(gender_dict)


    Age Name    Gender
0   45  John    M
1   38  Emily   F
```